# Adding days to a Date from an Array of JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

I have the following result from an operation on MongoDB.

Here is the result of the Order:

```
const orders = [{
    "price": 20200,
    "order_number": "19",
    "items": [{
      "product": {
        "_id": "60373f6e93af7d3e3239b21e",
        "title": "bb Set",
        "process_time": "10"
      },
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": 19000,
      "shipping": 1200,
    }],
    "createdAt": "2021-04-25T12:27:07.985Z",
  },
  {
    "price": 100,
    "order_number": "20",
    "items": [{
      "product": {
        "_id": "60373f6e93af7d3e3239b2op",
        "title": "Iron Set",
        "process_time": "12"
      },
      "quantity": 1,
      "price": 90,
      "shipping": 10,
    }],
    "createdAt": "2021-04-25T12:27:07.985Z",
  }
]
```

I want to add days of the `process_time` to the `createdAt` field and write the calculated date back to `process_time`.

This is how I did:

```
function getDeliveryTime(process_time, order_date) {
  let delivery_time = order_date + 1000 * 3600 * 24 * process_time
  return new Date(delivery_time).toLocaleDateString()
}

function updateProcess_time(orders) {
  for (const order of orders) {
    const createdOrder = order.createdAt
    for (const item of order.items) {
      item.product.process_time = getDeliveryTime(parseInt(item.product.process_time), new Date(createdOrder).getTime())
      console.log(item.product.process_time) // I get the value of the process_time at first iteration but get the value of calculated date in the 2nd iteration.
    }
    
  }
  return orders
}
```

The problem is that some of the dates are not calculated only few of them return the calculated date.But mostly I get `process_time: "Invalid Date"`.
I think the problem is that it doesnt wait until after all calculations are finished but returns the orders.

Comment: The issue is likely `process_time` not being the string representation of a number, or `createdAt` not being a ISO 8601 date. Maybe your MongoDB returns nulls?

Comment: I am more thinking about how I change the code so that it waits until all calculations are done before return.

Comment: @myadsmail , transfer the calculation part into another function and use the aync await to wait for the calculations to be completed

Comment: I dont know where to to use async/await in this code.

Comment: Changed the answer but still not getting the answer.

Answer (score 0):

process_time is a String not a number. You should wrap it in a call to `parseInt`.

Eg

```
getDeliveryTime(parseInt(item.product.process_time), new Date(createdOrder).getTime())
```

Comment: Not necessarily: `2 * '3' === 6`

Comment: Ah yeah I was testing with different values. Its still likely the issue

Comment: This or the date not being a valid ISO 8601 date

Comment: I changed to `Int` but still get errors. Because inside the loop it doesnt change the process_time.

Comment: Although I changed the answer.